# Store php script output to a variable in Shell

Tags: php, shell, stdout

I wanna save the output of the following command to a variable:

```
#!/bin/bash
php -f myFile.php
```

How can I do?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like so.

```
OUTPUT=`php -f myFile.php`
echo $OUTPUT
```